# Create Playlist without End-User auth - YouTube API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to figure out a way to create playlists, upload videos, and so on without having the user authentication themselves, but instead having the server do it for them using my YouTube account.

I started off by just doing a channel list adding the `mine` parameter since that requires authentication.

Here's the code I used and results can be seen at http://www.daysofthedead.net/testing/playlist.php

You can see at the bottom the code works because I can pull the results from a search which doesn't require authentication. But the channel list is empty, which does require authentication.

```
<?php
require_once 'GoogleClient/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'GoogleClient/contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php';

// Set your client id, service account name, and the path to your private key.
// For more information about obtaining these keys, visit:
// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts
const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxx8@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
const KEY_FILE = 'xxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google YouTube Sample");

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
// Google API Console when the service account was created.
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'),
    $key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$service = new Google_YouTubeService($client);

# User to search Youtube for.
$search_user = "BruceLeeOfficialPage";

# listSearch optional parameters
$search_optParams = array('part' => 'snippet', 'q' => $search_user, 'maxResults' => 2, 'type' => 'video');
# Search YouTube
$search = $service->search->listSearch($search_optParams);

# listChannels optional parameters.
$channel_optParams = array('maxResults' => 50, 'mine' => 'true');
# Get YouTube user's channel information
$channel = $service->channels->listChannels('snippet', $channel_optParams);

// We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
// Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>YouTube API v3 Sample App</h1></header>
<div class="box">

<?php if(isset($search)): ?>
<div class="search"><H1>Search:</H1>
<pre><?php print_r($search); ?></pre></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if(isset($channel)): ?>
<div class="channel"><H1>Channel:</H1>
<pre><?php print_r($channel); ?></pre></div>
<?php endif ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone able to help me out with this? Is there some kind of work around? Code examples would be extremely grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the OAuth 2 for Service Accounts flow, which isn't supported for the YouTube APIs. The list of supported flows is documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

In general, you need to go through one of the support flows once using a web browser, and from that point on you can make requests without user intervention.

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time understanding this version (v3) of the YouTube API but it looks like no matter which flow (I'd like to use server-size web app) I use there needs to be some sort of user interaction for what I want to do.

Comment: There needs to be an initial user interaction step where a real person authorizes access in a web browser. From that point on, you can reuse the generated OAuth 2 token without any user interaction.

Comment: So, there's not way to let a user upload videos to my YouTube account? Or can they after they authorize?

Comment: Please see http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html for a discussion on why you shouldn't allow your site's users to upload videos into your YouTube account.